# Implementing Flash in JavaFX WebEngine

Tags: flash, air, javafx-2

I understand that Adobe has a Flash API for Java called Air, but what would I use this for and would it be appropriate for a JavaFX `WebEngine`? I need some pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Air is not a Flash API for Java.

According to Adobe's [What is Air?](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/faq.html) FAQ:

> Adobe AIR is a cross-operating-system runtime that lets developers
>   combine HTML, JavaScript, Adobe Flash® and Flex technologies, and
>   ActionScript.

Air is used to:

> deploy rich Internet applications (RIAs) on a broad range of devices
>   ... AIR allows developers to ... build their applications and
>   easily deliver a single application installer that works across
>   operating systems.

Attempting to integrate Air and the JavaFX WebEngine is definitely the wrong direction.  Air is inappropriate for the JavaFX WebEngine as JavaFX has no notion of the Air runtime.